YAML Azure Pipelines Dynamic Passing of a Filepath Variable depending on Build Project
I am executing a single pipeline from 2 different projects. Repo1 and Repo2.
Repo2 is a submodule in Repo1.
In Repo 1 I am calling this:
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: pl
      type: git
      name: ###

stages:
- template: tool.yml@pl

However, the main YAML in repo 2 contains code which is executing as such
stages:

- stage: build_prj
  jobs:
  - job: config
    steps:
    - template: templates/git_control.yml

the main issue is in git_control Template
- task: CmdLine@1
  inputs:
    filename: Call
    arguments: '%PYTHON_HOME%\python %Build_Repository_LocalPath%\script.py'

Because the argument of BuildRepositoryLocalPath is different when executing from different areas. I need to change it according to what project is. when executing from the repo2 It will execute fine.
However when executing from repo1, %Build_Repository_LocalPath%\\script.py needs to be
%Build_Repository_LocalPath%\pipelines\support\repo2\script.py
I understand that a may have to manually write pipelines\\support\\repo2
But i can not get the passing of variables correct depending on the System.TeamProject which is the environmental variable I am using to distinguish between the 2 repos.
Tried Variables and Parameters. I think this is the way to go but cant get the syntax right.

As per System Variables, System.TeamProject is available in templates.
This means you can use a condition like ${{ if ... }} to set a variable with the right path for the project being used.
Example:
variables:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['System.TeamProject'], 'project1') }}: # replace with proper project name
    - name: 'scriptPath'
      value: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\pipelines\support\repo2\script.py'
  - ${{ if eq(variables['System.TeamProject'], 'project2') }}: # replace with proper project name
    - name: 'scriptPath'
      value: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\script.py'

steps:
  - checkout: self

  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.x'  # Specify the Python version you need
      addToPath: true
  
  - task: CmdLine@1
    inputs:
      filename: Call
      arguments: |
        python "$(scriptPath)"
    displayName: 'Run Python script using CmdLine task'

  # as an alternative, use script task
  - script: |
      python "$(scriptPath)"
    displayName: 'Run Python Script using script task'


This is the idea i want. But everytime i execute this as part of my pipeline, it fails to build? Also i am constrained to use CMDLINE
My first repo is calling a file in the second repo which is calling this as a template in the secnd repo also. If i comment out the variables section - again my pipeline builds successfully. My Pipeline is executing on AZ Devops

@user27194034 this is just a sample pipeline, you need to adapt your code to your specific scenario/use case. The most important part is using an ${{ if...}} condition to set the variable with the right path depending on the project/repository, and then using it in your task. Also, try using %PYTHON_HOME%\python instead of just python if you're not using the UsePythonVersion@0 task. If you have any errors please paste them here.

@user27194034 I just realized there was a small typo in the second if statement - it should be if eq(...) instead of if ne(...). I just fixed it, it should work now. My apologies.

Hi for some reason everytime i try and use 'variables' in my template it just doesnt build the pipeline and fails? Ive even tried just a standard dummy variable without the if logic

@user27194034 what is the problem? Is there any error message?
You're not able to queue a new build or is there an error when running the tasks?
Double-check the name of the projects and the paths of the scripts. Also, please note my sample pipeline is slightly different as compared to your code - for example, I'm installing python using UsePythonVersion@0 and I'm running python {script-path} instead of %PYTHON_HOME%\python {script-path}.

@user27194034 any update on this?

The predefined variable "System.TeamProject" is not to get the name of the repository. It is to get the name of team project which the pipeline is running in.
For example, a URL of Git repository in Azure DevOps is "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repository}", when running a pipeline for the {repository} in {project}, the variable "System.TeamProject" will return the name of '{project}' instead of '{repository}'.
For your case, if Repo1 and Repo2 are in the same team project, it is not possible to use the variable "System.TeamProject" to identify the pipeline is running for which repository. Instead, you can use the predefined variable "Build.Repository.Name" to identify the repository.
When a pipeline is triggered by Repo1, it will the value of "Build.Repository.Name" is the name of Repo1. When a pipeline is triggered by Repo2, the value is name of Repo2.
So, in the "templates/git_control.yml", you can set the condition like as below.
steps:
- task: CmdLine@1
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'Repo2')
  inputs:
    filename: call
    arguments: '%PYTHON_HOME%\python $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\script.py'

- task: CmdLine@1
  condition: ne(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'Repo2')
  inputs:
    filename: call
    arguments: '%PYTHON_HOME%\python $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\pipelines\support\repo2\script.py'

With above configuration, regardless of whether Repo1 and Repo2 are in the same project, when the pipeline is running for Repo2, the first CmdLine@1 task runs and the second gets skipped. Otherwise the first gets skipped and the second runs.


I don't think the OP is saying that he/she is trying to get the repository name using $(System.TeamProject). If I understood correctly, each repository is in a different project, so that variable is being used (indirectly) to know which repository to use. For example, if project1 is used then use repo1; otherwise use repo2.

@RuiJarimba, The repository Repo2 has some template YAML files, and the template files might be used reused by any pipelines from other repositories which are either in the same project or in the different projects. Getting the repository name can be more suitable.

"Getting the repository name can be more suitable" - I agree.
